# Inconsistent results from elementLocated vs findElements

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I am writing Webdriver automation for a web app.  I have a test that looks like this:

```
it('has five items', async function(done) {
  try {
    await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.className('item-class')),5000);
    const items = await driver.findElements(By.className('item-class'));
    expect(items.length).toBe(5);
    done();
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

This test will pass about 2/3 of the time, but will sometimes fail with:

```
Expected 0 to be 5.
```

I would think that there should be no way to get this response, since the first line is supposed to make it wait until some of these items exist.  I could understand a result of "Expected 1 to equal 5.", in the case that one item was added to the page, and the rest of the test completed before they were all there, but reaching the expect() call with 0 items on the page does not make sense to me.

The questions, then, are:

1) What am I missing / not understanding, such that this result is in fact possible?
2) Is there a different construct / method I should be using to make it wait until the expected items are on the page?

Comment: You are only waiting 5 seconds for the item-class elements to exist, if they don't load within 5 seconds, it continues execution and calls .findElements() which if after 5 seconds they don't exist you get an empty array. So, you could increase your wait time to more than 5 seconds, but you would have to determine what an acceptable cap on the wait time is.

Comment: I just ran it again, with the timeout increased to 15 seconds.  I got the same result, even though it completed this test in ~1 sec.

Comment: did you get the same error message 0 instead of 5?

Comment: Yes, I got "Expected 0 to be 5" again

Comment: you could build your own loop and just keep calling driver.findElements() until you get 5 or x amount of time has passed, in which case you fail at that point.

Comment: That is a possible workaround, which I may try.  To be clear, I am more interested at this point in finding out why the approach I have here does not work.  Or is it expected that calls be contained in loops to check whether the 'fail' response reoccurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the source code and `elementLocatedBy` uses `findElements`, see [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/until.js#L243). And `findElements` can return an empty array of elements after the timeout and hence `0` is expected (learnt something new today).

You can write something custom or use some ready-made method from [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/until.html) that doesn't use findElements

```
driver.wait(async function() {
  const items = await driver.findElements(By.className('item-class'))
  return items.length > 0;
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Learnt something new, indeed.  It looks like the construct I was using is not as useful as I'd hoped.  As I mentioned in the comments to the original answer, it looks like elementLocated(By...) is returning before the timeout, but now I have some idea as to where to start looking.  Thankee.

Comment: Cool. If this answer helps you, feel free to accept :)

Comment: @Phil I know that I'm terribly late, but with this solution did you always avoid the error? Just asking because I'm trying to understand what's the best way to wait an element and then work with it. For now, I've used the approach in the `try` block here at the top of the page...But I want a strong check that never fails =)

Answer (score 0):

well I think a good way to solve this issue would be

```
try {
const items = await driver.wait(until.elementsLocated(By.className('item-class')));
return items.length > 0;
}
catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
}
```

this way will always wait for ALL element**S** (it's elementSlocated) to be located and will return an array of items (remember that without `await` it will return an array of promises).
It has no timeout so it will wait until they are all ready (or you can put a limit so if something weird is happening you can see it).